# Is it possible to set up multiple local domains on localhost in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: networking, dns

I need unique, multiple domains all linked to my computer's local ip address. This is for testing purposes. I want to be able to have different local domains linked to different html files on my computer. For example, xxx.local and yyy.local will both be distinct but only accessible from my computer.

What I've tried: configuring apache2's sites-enabled and sites-available to have xxx.local and yyy.local's .conf files be linked to different DocumentRoots. However, it's not resolved, and when I link them to my computer's local ip address they both just link to html files already linked to my computer's localhost. Not to the html files specified by DocumentRoot in the .conf files.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by .local; are you just trying to have more than one local domain, or is .local something special?  It's easy to have multiple local domains, like xxx.local, yyy.local, zzz.dev, etc.  At least it is if you're using Apache.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. xxx.local, yyy.local, zzz.local, all linked to different html files on my computer. I'm a complete beginner and I can't figure it out still, I've been struggling for hours, can you please give me a detailed answer?..I'm so desperate to get this to work so I can continue learning front-end...

Comment: It's actually easy, but it's late here, so I'll give a brief guide, and fill in more or answer questions tomorrow.  So, I'll start on a quick answer below

Comment: I added a little more to my answer, showing an example of doing this from the outside world using noip ddns.  Same technique, but instead of modifying the hosts file, you set up ddns sites, and put those into the Apache config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the work is done in the configuration file in the directory  `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`, in a file called something like 000-default.conf.  This files will allow you to have multiple virtual domains, such as www.example.dev, or example.local, etc.  You set them up along with their directories in this file, and enter multiple sites in `/etc/hosts` to match.  All sites have the same localhost ip address, but the name directs it to the correct virtual host.

In this file, you need to clone the default settings as many times as you need, with something like this:

**Original contents**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

**Additional virtual host entries**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory  /var/www/html/site1>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot  /var/www/html/site1/ 
    ServerName site1.local
    ServerAlias www.site1.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory  /var/www/html/site2>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot  /var/www/html/site2/ 
    ServerName site2.local
    ServerAlias www.site2.local
</VirtualHost>

. . .
```

In order for the rewrite magic to work, you also need to make sure the rewrite engine is enabled.  This is done by creating a symbolic link in mods-enabled to a module in mods-available.  If you cd to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`, then enter `ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load`, it will enable the rewrite engine.

Then, in `/etc/hosts/`, you have matching entries like so:

```
127.0.0.1  site1.local
127.0.0.1  site2.local
```

This should get you going until I either complete this, or you have questions for me to answer.

**Answers to questions in comments 1**

One problem is the "DocumentRoot" directive: the directory specified is supposed to simply be the document root of the virtual site, which is most likely not "`/var/www/arcadr.local/html`" as specified.  Normally the site directory would be at the end.  "arcadr.local" is an arbitrary name, but matching the site is probably best.  So it should probably be "'/var/www/html/arcadr.local/'".

As far as the ln error, if I had had more time, I would have explained that the bottom line is you need a symbolic link named "rewrite.load" in the `mods-enabled` directory that links to the actual file in the `mods-available` directory.  So evidently, you already had it, and didn't really need to do it again, but as long as it's there, it should work.

Try the one change, and also try to understand what it's doing.  It's actually pretty understandable, and once you start understanding, you'll learn more.

By the way, the "alias" directive isn't necessary, I just added that to illustrate how you could do it if you want.

**Answers to questions in comments 2**

The default html file is simply one of now several virtual hosts specified in the file 000-default.conf.  Note I originally left off the ".conf" extension of the file.  Did you find that correct file?  It must be in "`sites-enabled`", not "`sites-available`".  Same as for the mods, you can have multiple sites *available*, but you need to have one *enabled*, and the default is "`000-default.conf`" (unless it has changed since I set it up).

You say "arcadr.local just redirects me to another .local website connected to my localhost."  Make sure you have this configuration file set up correctly.  It should have a series of blocks, like html:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Each virtual host must start and end with these directives, and you cannot have one embedded in another.

You can find some good documentation and examples on the apache.org website.  This is where I learned how to set up the files.  My advice is to keep it simple, and if you add anything you don't understand, do it one step at a time, and remove anything that doesn't work.  Here are some examples:  [VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

**Some additional pointers**

Whenever you make changes to the configuration file at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, you need to restart the Apache server.  I use the command `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` to do this.  **Edit**: Gabriel posted a better command for this:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

But both commands will work, at least for now.

This same technique works for dynamic DNS servers such as noip.com, dyndns, etc.  For example, I just made 3 sample sites on my home system.  If my computer is on, you can try it to see.  If you check, you'll see that all 3 sites have the exact same IP address, but go to different virtual sites (variations on the default, which you can see at `leftcoast.noip.us`

```
http://site1.leftcoast.noip.us/
http://site2.leftcoast.noip.us/
http://site3.leftcoast.noip.us/
```

Comment: Ok, right now I have: `DocumentRoot /var/www/arcadr.local/html ServerName arcadr.local ServerAlias www.arcadr.local` in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. I put `ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load` into my terminal, but it gave me an error so I used `ln -sf ../mods-available/rewrite.load` instead. I edited `/etc/hosts/` to give me: 127.0.0.1 localhost   127.0.0.1       reddit.local 127.0.0.1       arcadr.local       But it still doesn't work. Both arcadr.local and reddit.local link me to the contents of localhost.

Comment: @AndresArana: see answer at end of post.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not working for me. I changed the directory so that my new `index.html` is now in `/var/www/html/arcadr.local` and changed the `DocumentRoot` accordingly.  The sym link exists. My /etc/hosts/ file is edited correctly to match the ServerName in `000.default.conf`. `arcadr.local`'s index html file can open in my browser, but not through its `arcadr.local` ServerName. I even tried this in a 14.04 VM and changed the directory to`/var/www/html/arcadr/` instead. `arcadr.local` always sends me to the VM's localhost, which is the apache2 default page for my VM.

Comment: By the way there is no rewrite.load  in my mods-enabled, only in my mods-available.

Comment: @AndresArana:  There does need to be that link; that's what enables it to happen.  Did you enter the command in the mods-enabled directory?  Sounds like you may have entered it in the mods-available directory, which is why it said it already existed.  Creating the link *enables* an *available* mod.

Comment: You were right. I corrected that mistake, I now have the same `rewrite.load` in both `mods-available` and `mods-enabled`. I double checked the root directory and it's as you suggested: `/var/www/html/arcadr.local/`. But it still doesn't respect the DirectoryRoot that's supposedly linked to my `arcadr.local` ServerName, `arcadr.local` just redirects me to another .local website connected to my localhost. The only thing that comes to mind now is that my localhost is not connected to the default apache2 html file on my local computer. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @AndresArana: No.  See notes at the end of my original answer.  It's really not too complicated, but I think you haven't quite seen the big picture yet, which may be my fault for not communicating it better.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you so much. I was able to get it working on a VM after I restarted the apache2 server. I have other unrelated problems with the server running on my local machine but that is a smaller problem that I'll hopefully solve on my own. By the way you did a good job of communicating it I just came into this with beginner linux/zero networking knowledge.

Comment: @AndresArana: About 5 - 6  years or so ago (at the age of 62), I didn't even know how to begin setting up a server, or creating a web site.  It began mostly as a hobby.  Now I've done a few professionally, done troubleshooting professionally, and use Vim (actually mostly gvim)  for editing the sites (I love using gvim and Linux now).

Comment: i completely automated this process, you might want to look into https://github.com/Silberlachs/serverProject/blob/main/multipage

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps you need to take to do that.

First it to point out to your computer that you want him to look for xxx.local and yyy.local at 127.0.0.1, which usually means localhost or your computer.

This is made by editing your `/etc/hosts` file.

Then you have to configure your webserver to answer differently according to which serverName is being asked for, which is done by fiddling with apache virtual hosts.

Marty's answer is pretty complete in regards to that subject. And don't forget to `sudo service apache2 restart` so it reloads it's configurations.

Also, can you pastebin your virtual hosts configurations?

Comment: Solved. `sudo service apache2 restart` did it. Thank you!

Comment: Upvote for the better restart command - I had the obsolete one in my notes, and didn't remember the one you used, which is better (although both will work).  Also, kudos for mentioning the need to restart.  I had added it later, but kept forgetting along the way.